# Why is 'All' getting removed from my enum list in Bot Framework

Tags: c#, botframework

I have the below enum with a list of companies, and I want bot user to be able to choose all of them.  But when the enum list is displayed, 'All' is getting removed.
Is there an internal bot command that will allow user to select All items?
I am having trouble finding documentation on this.

Also, should I be using the Term attribute to solve this?

```
public enum Companies
{
    //[Terms("except", "but", "not", "no", "all", "everything")]
    All,
    CompanyA,
    CompanyB,
    CompanyC,
    CompanyD    
}
```

Comment: Is that how the code looks with the edit?  Or can we assume that All is commented out?

Comment: All is not commented out.  Just the Terms attribute is commented out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow

> If a form field is based on an enumeration property that is not
>   nullable, the value 0 in the enumeration represents null (i.e.,
>   indicates that the field does not have a value), and you should start
>   your enumeration values at 1. FormFlow ignores all other property
>   types and methods.

You can supply a 'none' option:

```
public enum Companies
{
    None,
    All,
    CompanyA,
    CompanyB,
    CompanyC,
    CompanyD    
}
```

Or, specify the value for each item starting at 1:

```
public enum Companies
{
    All=1,
    CompanyA=2,
    CompanyB=3,
    CompanyC=4,
    CompanyD=5    
}
```